# How can I delete my older versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove/hide old kernel versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions)

I'm running from a low disk space two Ubuntu versions. I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 in a 6 GB disk partition, but after I updated it, the boot manager shows an older version of Ubuntu in the O.S. menu. I want to delete this old version so that I can free up disk space, as only 1 GB is left now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootloader shows "Older Versions of Ubuntu" this means older Kernel version actually, you can use programs like  [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)  that let you run a janitor thruought your system and delete innecesary files such as older kernel versions

You can also use Synaptic Package Manager to do that, here  [Nixie Pixel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FYW2nGv4gs&feature=plcp)  explains it all in a cool little video :)

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the older Ubuntu version using Gparted to delete the partition where it's installed and later expanding the partition you want to occupy this empty space. Don't forget to save the files you have inside this partition (the one with old Ubuntu version).

To install Gparted type the following command on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

You can also install it via the Ubuntu Software Center

After modifying the partitions type the following command on the terminal to update the O.S. selection menu list:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Actually, these are not full-fledged Ubuntu installations and no extraneous partitions were added. These are just kernel versions.